# Pong Game in Processing - Problems with keyPressed() and keyReleased()

Tags: java, processing, pong

I'm having a problem programming a pong game in Processing that's driving me crazy. The paddles work fine at first. But after a little bit of time, they fail to respond and lock up, seemingly at random. I put in some code to see what was wrong, and the program sometimes fails to register keyPressed(), but will print keyReleased() when I let go of the key. I've checked out other threads and am at a loss as to what's going on. (For homework, but our instructor encourages posting on Stack Overflow.)

Here's a sample log. The last line is the problem. I pressed "d" and released it. Note that "d" is shown as released, but not pressed. It doesn't make sense to me...

KEY PRESSED: d

KEY RELEASED: d

KEY PRESSED: a

KEY RELEASED: a

KEY RELEASED: d

*Edit* 
I actually just went and set my "Key Repeat" settings to "Off," and it seems to have fixed the problem! (I'm on macOS Sierra.) Why might this be? Is there a way for me to alter my code so that this bug wouldn't affect anyone else?

```html
// Pong Game
// Starter Code
import java.util.*;

Ball ball;
Paddle paddle1;
Paddle paddle2;
HeadsUp hup;

boolean right;
boolean left;
boolean a;
boolean d;

void setup() {
  frameRate(100);
  size(300, 600);
  hup = new HeadsUp();
  paddle1 = new Paddle();
  paddle2 = new Paddle();
  paddle2.setY(height * .05);
  ball = new Ball();
}

public void keyPressed() {
  println("KEY PRESSED: " + key);
  changeDirection(true);
}

public void keyReleased() {
  println("KEY RELEASED: " + key); 
  changeDirection(false);
}

public void changeDirection(boolean val) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    left = val;
  }
  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    right = val;
  }
  if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
    a = val;
  }
  if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
    d = val;
  }
}

private void updatePaddles(){
  if (left) {
    paddle1.moveLeft();
  }
  if (right) { 
    paddle1.moveRight();
  }
  if (a) {
    paddle2.moveLeft();
  }
  if (d) {
    paddle2.moveRight();
  }
}



void draw() {
  if (!hup.isGameOver()) {
    background(0);
    updatePaddles();
    paddle1.draw();
    paddle2.draw();
    hup.draw();
    ball.draw();
    if (ball.update(hup, paddle1, paddle2)) { 
      ball = new Ball();  
    }
  }
  else {
    stop();
  }
}


void stop(){
  background(0);
  noLoop();
  PFont f = createFont("Menlo", 16, true);
  textFont(f);
  fill(255);
  text("GAME OVER!", 100, 300);
  if (hup.p1BallsLeft != 0) {
    text("Player One Wins!", 80, 350);
  } else {
    text("Player Two Wins!", 80, 350);
  }
}

class Paddle {
  float x;
  float y;
  float w;
  float h;
  
  Paddle() {
    w = 75;
    h = 15;
    x = width / 4;
    y = height * .9;
  }
  
  public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  public void moveLeft() {
    if (x >= 0) x -= 2;
  }
  
  public void moveRight() {
    if (x < 225) x += 2;
  }
    
  private void draw() {
      fill(255);
      rect(x, y, w, h, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
  }
}

class Ball {
  PVector position;
  PVector velocity;
  static final int BALL_WIDTH = 16;
  static final int BALL_HEIGHT = 16;
  static final int BALL_RADIUS = BALL_WIDTH / 2;
  
  
  Ball() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean direction = rand.nextBoolean();
    float vel = 2;
    if (direction) vel *= -1;
    position = new PVector(rand.nextInt(300), 300);
    velocity = new PVector(2, vel);
  }
  
  boolean update(HeadsUp hup, Paddle paddle1, Paddle paddle2) {
    position.add(velocity);
    if (position.y > height) {
      hup.update(1);
      return true;
    }
    if (position.y < 0) {
      hup.update(2);
      return true;
    }
    checkIfHitWall();
    if (velocity.y > 0) checkIfHitPaddle(paddle1);
    else checkIfHitPaddle(paddle2);
    return false;
}
  
  void draw() {
      fill(#ffff00);
      ellipse(position.x, position.y, BALL_WIDTH, BALL_HEIGHT);
  }
  
  void checkIfHitWall() {
    if ((position.x > width) || (position.x < 0)) {
      velocity.x *= -1;
    }
    if (position.y < 0) {
      velocity.y *= -1;
    }
  }
  
  void checkIfHitPaddle(Paddle paddle) {
    
    float distX = Math.abs(position.x - paddle.x - paddle.w / 2);
    float distY = Math.abs(position.y - paddle.y - paddle.h /2);
    boolean check = false;
    if (distX > (paddle.w / 2 + BALL_RADIUS)) { return; }
    if (distY > (paddle.h / 2 + BALL_RADIUS)) { return; }
    if (distX <= (paddle.w/2)) { check = true; } 
    if (distY <= (paddle.h/2)) { check = true; }
    float dx = distX - paddle.w / 2;
    float dy = distY - paddle.h / 2;
    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= (BALL_RADIUS * BALL_RADIUS)) check = true;
    if (check) {
      velocity.y *= -1;
    }
  }
}

class HeadsUp {
  int p1BallsLeft;
  int p2BallsLeft;
  boolean gameOver;
  
  HeadsUp() {
    p1BallsLeft = 3;
    p2BallsLeft = 3;
    gameOver = false;
  }
  
  void draw() {
    text("Player 1 Balls Left: " + p1BallsLeft + "\nPlayer 2 Balls Left: " + p2BallsLeft, 125, 300 );
  }
  
  void update(int player) {
    if (player == 1) {  
      p1BallsLeft--;
    }
    if (player == 2) {
      p2BallsLeft--;
    }
    if (p1BallsLeft == 0 || p2BallsLeft == 0) gameOver = true;
    if (!hup.isGameOver()) {
    }
  }
  
  boolean isGameOver() {
    
    return gameOver;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that shows the problem? We don't need to see any of your game logic, just print statements are fine.

Comment: @KevinWorkman If he's unsure where the problem is though then I don't see a problem with posting what he has.  It's not pages and pages of code, it's still pretty concise.

Comment: @KevinWorkman

Here's a sample log. The last line is the problem. I pressed "d" and released it. Note that "d" is shown as released, but not pressed. It doesn't make sense to me...

KEY PRESSED: d
KEY RELEASED: d
KEY PRESSED: a
KEY RELEASED: a
KEY RELEASED: d

Comment: @JonTaylor The code posted does not compile because it contains variables that aren't defined. This is not the OP's entire codebase. Instead of adding more code to make it runnable, I suggest the OP creates a [mcve] instead.

Comment: @tom_dub That log doesn't really tell us much. We really need to see a [mcve] if you want help debugging your code.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I've posted compilable code above. I actually just went and set my "Key Repeat" settings to "Off," and it seems to have fixed the problem! (I'm on macOS Sierra.) Why might this be? Is there a way for me to alter my code so that this bug wouldn't affect anyone else?

Comment: @tom_dub I'm not trying to be annoying, but code you post should be minimal. If you're just asking about the event functions, you shouldn't include all that extra game code. That just makes it harder to debug the problem.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I really have to disagree.  Yes there were bits missing but actually including much of the code could be necessary in debugging an issue like this if in fact it is something in the draw loop affecting the registration of key presses.  When the OP has no idea where the problem might be and even looking at it doesn't look obvious then posting a fuller example can be useful.

Comment: @JonTaylor The OP found out that the problem is a hardware setting. A simple sketch that included just the `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased()` functions would have been enough to show that, and it would have made it more obvious that it **wasn't** something in the draw loop. The fact that you think it's something in the draw loop proves that a MCVE would have been better at actually showing the real problem. We don't need to see stuff like the heads up display when it has nothing do to with user input. MCVE is a pretty standard Stack Overflow request, and I'm surprised you're unfamiliar.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks for the advice. I'm new to the SO community, so I'll keep that in mind if I have other questions. Is there a way to make sure this doesn't affect other machines? It seems strange that macOS and Processing would have such incompatibilities. And I haven't come across this problem anywhere else on the web. It seems that more people should have had this sort of problem.

Comment: @KevinWorkman He edited his question to state he had then found a tech setting, this was not in the original question.  Originally he had no clue what was causing the issue.  The fact the draw loop is what is calling the checks for key presses is a valid reason for keeping the draw loop intact in the question.  I'm not sure why you assume I'm not familiar with MCVE, check my questions out and I'm sure you'll see I always include the bits that are needed.  I just don't think it's necessarily appropriate in this case (before the edit).

Comment: @JonTaylor I really have no interest in bickering with you, so let's not hijack this comment thread. If you're familiar with the idea of an MCVE then you should know that it's an important step in the problem-solving process to isolate the problem. If OP has no idea what's causing the issue, that's all the more reason to do some debugging and try to get it down to the smallest reproducible code. You don't include code because you think it might have something to do with the problem. You include code because you **know** it does. That's the whole point. But let's agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and ran it to find out the problem and your problem is not definitely in the `keyReleased()` function. When you press a key and then release it, it should only say it once, when I pressed the a and s buttons, it came out as this:

> KEY PRESSED: a
>
> KEY PRESSED: s
>
> KEY PRESSED: a
>
> KEY PRESSED: s

Now what I believe your program is thinking is that since the a and s keys were pressed then released at the same time, it's assuming that I tapped the a and s keys, which makes it believe that they were pressed and then released at the same time.

The only advice I could give to you is to do a debug process to see where your error is.